# OWIN cookie based authentication middleware can't change cookie name

Tags: authentication, cookies, owin, owin-middleware

I am trying to rename the authentication cookie by doing the following:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login"),
    CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest,
    SlidingExpiration = false,
    CookieName = "mycookiename"
});
```

When I run the app from IIS Express and check the cookie name in Fiddler, the cookie name is set to "mycookiename" as expected.  However, when I deploy the site, the cookie name is still set as ".AspNet.ApplicationCookie".  Is there something I'm missing on how to get this change to work?  Is there something in IIS that can override my application settings?

Answer (score 0):

IIS has own session configuration in session state. You can try put into web.config:

```
<sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" cookieName="mycookiename" mode="InProc" useHostingIdentity="true" />
```

For more info visit MSDN website: https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/cc754450%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: this will set the session cookie not the authentication cookie .